# 2D char array issues with input and output

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble with this homework problem. We are basically making a "labyrinth" populated by characters. However, I'm not sure how to even get started because I have issues with creating the 2D char array. Here is my current code:

```
char** read_labyrinth  (int* rows, int* cols)
{ 
    cin >> *rows >> *cols;

   char **labyrinth = NULL;
   labyrinth = new char*[(*rows)]

   for (int i = 0; i < (*rows); i++)
   {
         labyrinth[i] = new char[(*cols)];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < (*rows); i++)

   {
       cin >> labyrinth[i];   
   }

  return labyrinth;
}
```

I also have this to print the labyrinth, but nothing is ever printed out. The program is started be doing something like ./labyrinth > labyrinth1.in 
where the text file has two numbers for rows and cols as well as a bunch of characters like #* to populate, but nothing has ever been outputted for me. If anything, rows and cols seem to get set with garbage values, so I figure I must be doing something terribly wrong. Here is the print function

```
void print_labyrinth (char** maze, int rows, int cols)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
            cout << maze[i];
      }

}
```

Thank you for any help. I'm quite lost.

Comment: Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: The homework problem asks that I make a 2D character array, so I'm stuck with that.

Comment: @mock_blatt the overload for `operator <<` *does* exist for `std::ostream` and `char const*`. So "right off the bat"... isn't. However, that doesn't address a severe underlying issue with this code, that `cin >> maze[i]` will expect to terminate the string, which will invoke UB if indeed there are `*cols` number of characters being read. There will be no space for the terminator, and thus, ouch.

Comment: Oops, I realized that I made a typo by putting maze[i] instead of labyrinth[i], but still, it sounds like I'm doing something pretty bad.

Comment: @zettaucla yeah, I missed that tree in the forest due to the defect I pointed out prior. Honestly, why you're not using `std::vector<std::string>` or similar for this is beyond me.

Comment: @VolAnd Thanks for the help, but I'm still a bit lost. At least now, it seems to be printing out blank rows instead of nothing like it was before. I was wondering if there's maybe something special I need to do with cin to extract information from the text file. The instructions say not to use ifstream or anything related to a file, so that's throwing me off. The value for my int row pointer seems to stay at 0 since it doesn't get any values. Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: @zettaucla To extract (read) data from file with cin you should redirect standard input when running progam, like `./labyrinth < labyrinth1.in` but in that case you will lose possibility to input something from keyboard

Comment: @zettaucla To find problems with reading characters from file I recommend  to make output for read information to see the problem.... Perhaps, some escape characters like \n\r (newline, etc.) or spaces (including tabs) should be skipped in the reading process

Comment: If you have example of input file, update your question with such example

Comment: @volAnd You know what, I realized that the one of the files was entirely empty. When I tried other sample text files that were provided, it worked. Thanks again for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from point that 2D needs 2 dimensions, I mean, for output you need two nested for-loops (this will works for data of any type, not only for `char`, but of course output for car can be made using C-style-strings, i.e. `char*`, if you store `'\0'` - now you DO NOT!), e.g.:

```cpp
void print_labyrinth (char** maze, int rows, int cols)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
         {
            cout << maze[i][j];
         }
         cout << endl;
      }

}
```

Similar problem I see in memory allocation and filling part... consider changing and moving loop with `cin >> maze[i]` inside the first loop of `read_labyrinth`, e.g.:

```cpp
   for (int i = 0; i < (*rows); i++)
   {
         // memory allocation for row
         maze[i] = new char[(*cols)];
         // data reading to allocated mempory
         for (int j = 0; j < (*cols); j++)
         {
             cin >> maze[i][j];
         }
   }
```

Also I recommend you checking results of memory allocation with `if(maze != NULL)` and `if(maze[i] != NULL)` before writing something to memory

Answer (score 0):

This basic sample worked for me :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char** read_labyrinth  (int rows, int cols)
{ 

   char **labyrinth = NULL;
   labyrinth = new char*[rows];

   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)  {
         labyrinth[i] = new char[cols];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)   {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      {
          cin >> labyrinth[i][j];   
      }
   }
  return labyrinth;
}
void print_labyrinth (char** maze, int rows, int cols)
{
    cout << "labyrinth is : \n";
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                cout << maze[i][j];
            }
               cout<<"\n";
      }    
}
int main() 
{
    int r, c;
    cout << "enter no of rows and columns \n";
    cin >> r >> c;
    print_labyrinth(read_labyrinth(r,c),r,c);
    return 0;
}
```

Online editor link [ideone - link](https://ideone.com/8cujDW)

You do need too take care to free the memory still.